# Who is obliged / authorised to pay maintenance fee?

Tags: fees, license, payment

In the licensee agreement (exclusive license) there is a clause that licensee shall cover all fees and related patenting costs.
Can the indication of a licensee agreement be entered in the USPTO patent register? Will in that case the USPTO invite the licensee to pay the fees or how this could be manged?

How is this issue resolved in procedures before China's IPO and European patent Office?